# Правки по переводу (пропущенные пробелы)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В некоторых [строках](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/viewstrings/#ru/english/40264224?qt=%D0%BD%D0%B0%24) пропущены пробелы, из за чего получается что-нибудь вроде:

```
ожидающая правка наОтключение все коннекций в пуле
```

В принципе, это видно по оригинальному тексту:

4996 pending edit o**n $**postLink$

4996 ожидающая правка н**а$**postLink$

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо.